# Mills' constant calculation

Tags: number-theory

How simple method can be calculated with very high precision (hundreds of thousands of decimal places) Mills' constant?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant

Answer (score 3):

So far there is no method to this. Assuming RH and other unproven conjectures one can approximate Mill's constant, but "only" like $6850$ digits. See Cadwell's recent paper [Determining Mills’ Constant and a Note on Honaker’s Problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.4883) from $2013$ (the last lines of section $3$ on page $6$).

Answer (score 2):

Only way we know of is computing this constant from backwards - we first find the primes we are interested in and then compute what constant $A$ will give us the primes we found when using $\lfloor A^{3^n}\rfloor$. Rate of growth is doubly exponential, which quickly limits our ability to get more precision.